# Plyr mapvalues to rename levels giving unexpected result

Tags: r

I am trying to use mapvalues to rename a long list of levels of a factor. As it seemed not to be working correctly, I produced a simple example showing the issue.

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c","c","d","a")
y <- c("a", "c", "c","d","d","b")
z<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))

levels(z$y)<-mapvalues(z$y, c("a", "c","b"), c("A", "C","m"))
levels(z$x)<-mapvalues(z$x, c("a", "c","b"), c("A", "C","m"))
```

## Answer:

```
>z
x y
1 A A
2 m C
3 C C
4 C d
5 C d
6 A C
```

As can be seen, `$x[5]` should be "d" and `$y[6]` should be "m". I also tried applying "as.character" to "from" "to" vectors but it didn't work either. I'm working in RStudio, Mac version, R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo". Thanks for help.

Comment: Dont' assign to `levels`  Or elsse you have to assign wit the `levels` of the output `levels(z$y) <- levels(plyr::mapvalues(z$y, c("a", "c","b"), c("A", "C","m")))`

Comment: Thanks, now I see, should assign to variable: z$x <-mapvalues(z$x,from,to)

Comment: Just want to point out that `plyr` was retired some time back in favor of (primarily) `dplyr`, along with other tidyverse packages

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the output of

```
plyr::mapvalues(z$y, c("a", "c","b"), c("A", "C","m"))
#[1] A C C d d m
#Levels: A m C d
```

It is a vector with the same length as 'x', while the `levels` length is different

If we assign this output to the `levels(z$y`)`, there is length difference.  We can either do the assignment to the whole column

```
z$y <- plyr::mapvalues(z$y, c("a", "c","b"), c("A", "C","m"))
```

Or change the `levels` with the corresponding `levels`

```
levels(z$y) <- levels(plyr::mapvalues(z$y, c("a", "c","b"), c("A", "C","m")))
```